# How to pass command line arguments to ipython

Tags: python, ipython

Is there any way that I pass arguments to my python script through command line while using ipython? Ideally I want to call my script as:

```
ipython -i script.py --argument blah
```

and I want to be able to have `--argument` and `blah` listed in my `sys.argv`.

Comment: Normally you'd use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/argparse.html). No idea when using ipython.

Comment: But I guess `argparse` also uses `sys.argv` to parse the arguments.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use one `--` more option before that:

```
ipython  script.py -- --argument blah
```

Help of `Ipython`:

```
ipython [subcommand] [options] [-c cmd | -m mod | file] [--] [arg] ...

If invoked with no options, it executes the file and exits, passing the
remaining arguments to the script, just as if you had specified the same
command with python. You may need to specify `--` before args to be passed
to the script, to prevent IPython from attempting to parse them. If you
specify the option `-i` before the filename, it will enter an interactive
IPython session after running the script, rather than exiting.
```

Demo:

```
$ cat script.py 
import sys
print(sys.argv)

$ ipython  script.py -- --argument blah
['script.py', '--argument', 'blah']

$ ipython  script.py -- arg1 arg2
['script.py', 'arg1', 'arg2']
```

Comment: And how do you do it without specifying the file to run?

Comment: @rjurney, use `ipython  -i  arg1 arg2`

Comment: Does `--` have any semantic meaning on its own, ala `|` and `>` in terminals, or is this just convention?

Comment: @TankorSmash just convention.  If you look in argv you'll just see it listed as another argument.  Note that git uses this extensively.