# Python: executing a terminal command from jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to run C++ simulations from a jupyter notebook. The program needs three values in input, i.e. `10`, `0.2` and `0.6`.

This what I am doing now and it works fine:

```
## Compile
! mpicxx -o main main.cpp Node.cpp Agent.cpp -std=gnu++11
## Run
! mpirun -np 1 ./main 10 0.2 0.6
```

But if try to declare those values before, it does not recognizes them.

```
a = 10
b = 0.2
c = 0.6
! mpirun -np 1 ./main a b c
```

Comment: @YaserM yes I did

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing IPython variables as arguments to bash commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497069/passing-ipython-variables-as-arguments-to-bash-commands)

Answer (score 2):

you need to type it like this

```
a = 10
b = 0.2
c = 0.6
! mpirun -np 1 ./main {a} {b} {c}
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like (from [this document](http://mmcdan.github.io/posts/interacting-with-the-shell-via-jupyter-notebook/)) you can wrap your Python variables in curly braces or else prefix them with the `$` to get the to expand for the shell.  E.g., `! mpirun -np 1 ./main {a} {b} {c}`

Answer (score 1):

```
! mpirun -np 1 ./main {a} {b} {c}
```

---

```
! mpirun -np 1 ./main $a $b $c
```