# Jupyter notebooks: how to run a terminal command with a python variable input

Tags: python, command-line, jupyter-notebook

From my Jupyter/IPython notebook I need to run an R script from a terminal command, using a Python variable as input:

```
x = "Owen" 
! Rscript ./sayHello.R x
```

However, the variable `x` is not recognized (ie. Python namespace is not included). How can you address this?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55416796/python-executing-a-terminal-command-from-jupyter-notebook , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497069/passing-ipython-variables-as-arguments-to-bash-commands

Comment: Admins, welcome to close this as a duplicate. I felt it was best to post the question as it uses different keywords so it was hard to find these duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

Solution: Enclose variables in braces:

```
x = "Owen" 
! Rscript ./sayHello.R {x}
```

or prefix by a `$` sign:

```
x = "Owen"
! Rscript ./sayHello.R $x
```