# Passing Ipython variables as string arguments to shell command

Tags: python, shell, ipython

How do I execute a shell command from Ipython/Jupyter notebook passing the value of a python string variable as a string in the bash argument like in this example:

```
sp_name = 'littleGuy' #the variable

sp_details = !az ad app list --filter "DisplayName eq '$sp_name'" #the shell command
```

I've tried using `$sp_name` alone, `${sp_name}`, `{sp_name}` etc as outlined in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497069/passing-ipython-variables-as-arguments-to-bash-commands), but none have worked.

The kicker here is the variable name needs to be quoted as a string in the shell command.

**EDIT1:**

@manu190466. I was judging from the string output that your solution worked. It appears for some reason it does not in practice. I wonder if `az ad app list` URL encodes the query or something...?

Thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The main problem you encounters seems to come from the quotes needed in your string.
You can keep the quotes in your string by using a format instruction and a raw string.

Use a 'r' before the whole string to indicate it is to be read as raw string, ie: special caracters have to not be interpreted. A raw string is not strictly required in your case because the string constructor of python is able to keep single quotes in a double quotes declaration but I think it's a good habit to use raw string declarators when there are non alphanumerics in it.

There are at least two way to format strings :

Older method herited from ancient langages with % symbols:

```
sp_name = 'littleGuy' #the variable
sp_query = r"DisplayName eq '%s'"%(sp_name) 

sp_details = !az ad app list --filter {sp_query}
```

Newer method with {} symbols and the format() method :

```
sp_name = 'littleGuy' #the variable
sp_query = r"DisplayName eq '{}'".format(sp_name) 

sp_details = !az ad app list --filter {sp_query}
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you.
`sp_query = r"DisplayName eq '{}'".format(sp_name)`, 
`sp_query`,
`"DisplayName eq 'python-sp'"`

Comment: Is this supposed to work in the pure ipython shell (CLI, not the Jupyter notebook) as well? It didn't seem to for me, but maybe that's because I had some extra quoting in my case.

Answer (score 0):

would you try something like this:

```
sp_name = 'littleGuy' #the variable
sp_query = "DisplayName eq "+sp_name 

sp_details = !az ad app list --filter {sp_query}
```

Comment: Same error as before. The `sp_name` needs additional quotes within the `DisplayName eq` string. Should be `"DisplayName eq 'littleGuy'"`.
`sp_name = 'littleGuy'
sp_query = "DisplayName eq " + sp_name
sp_details = !az ad app list {sp_query} > sp_details2.json
sp_details`

`['ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: DisplayName eq littleGuy',
 'usage: az [-h] [--verbose] [--debug]',
 '          [--output {json,jsonc,table,tsv,yaml,none}] [--query JMESPATH]',
 '          {ad} ...']`

Comment: what if you add quotation to you sp_name?
like "'littleGuy'"

Comment: Tried `sp_name = "littleGuy"`, `sp_name = "'littleGuy'"` and `sp_name = '"littleGuy"'`. Same error result.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be also resolved using something like below

```py
sp_name = 'littleGuy' #the variable
sp_details = !az ad app list --filter "DisplayName eq '{sp_name}'"
```

Comment: Hm. I still receive an error on this one `ERROR: az: error: unrecognized arguments: eq \'littleGuy\'"',`

Comment: @SeaDude, can you comment what command you run when you are using a bash terminal

Comment: Sure. `sp_name = 'littleGuy'
sp_details = !az ad app list --filter \"DisplayName eq \'{sp_name}\'\"
sp_details`

Comment: Not this. Open a terminal and run the command in a bash and tell me what command you ran. Without `iPython`

Comment: IPython is the subject of this question as well as my only python env. I'm running terminal commands from IPython, with no alternatives, in this case.

Comment: Okie, can you try `!az ad app list --filter "DisplayName eq '{sp_name}'"`?