# how to write gsutil script if destination is variable

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I need to copy keras model from local to gcp storage bucket, my code is as below:

```
output_path = 'gs://bucket/folder/'
output_prefix = 'modelprefix_'+str(num)+'_'

model.save('_model.h5')
fn_model = output_path + output_prefix + '_model.h5'
!gsutil -m cp '_model.h5' fn_model
```

However, the above code was not able to move saved model to bucket storage, instead it just saved another file as name 'fn_model' locally.

How to copy or move local file to gcp bucket storage with a variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of the variable to be used in your shell command, I think you'll need to prefix it with a dollar sign, e.g. `$fn_model`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497069/passing-ipython-variables-as-arguments-to-bash-commands).